# Count how many parent nodes have the same Tag's 'value' in an XML file

Tags: javascript, xml

i currently have a javascript function that counts how many elements i have by a particular Tag, which is easy enough. I'm also wondering if there is also an easy way to count the number of elements (or parent elements) that contain a Tags inner value.

My XML file is set up similar to this, each level 3 nesting has the same tags:

```
<GAMECATALOG>
  <PS4>
    <SHOOTER>
      <NAME>Shootergame</NAME>
      <PRODUCER>Microsoft</PRODUCER>
    </SHOOTER>
    <SHOOTER>
      <NAME>Shootergame2</NAME>
      <PRODUCER>UbiSoft</PRODUCER>
    </SHOOTER>
    <HORROR>
      <NAME>Horrorgame</NAME>
      <PRODUCER>UbiSoft</PRODUCER>
    </HORROR>  
  </PS4>
  <XBOX>
    <ADVENTURE>
      <NAME>Shootergame</NAME>
      <PRODUCER>Microsoft</PRODUCER>
    </ADVENTURE>
    <RPG>
      <NAME>Horrorgame</NAME>
      <PRODUCER>UbiSoft</PRODUCER>
    </RPG>       
  </XBOX>
</GAMECATALOG>
```

Example javascript code:

```
var numOfPs4 = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("PS4")[0].children.length;
var numOfXbox = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("XBOX")[0].children.length;
var totalGames = numOfShooters + numOfAdventure;

//find the total number of each of the game types within PS4
var numOfShooters = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("SHOOTER").length;
var numOfHorrors = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("HORROR").length;


//find the total number of each of the game types within XBOX
var numOfAdventure = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("ADVENTURE").length;
var numOfRpg = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("RPG").length;


// count the number of games of a specific producer
var numOfUbiSoft = ???
```

Now my XML is a lot longer then this, but everything is counting correctly. Now i just need to be able to find how many elements contain the value of UbiSoft in the producer tag. Either the parents of these tags or simply how many times the value appears in the document, which in this example should give me 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
const producers = xml.getElementsByTagName("PRODUCER");
const numUbiSoft = Array.from(producers).filter((producer) => producer.innerHTML === 'UbiSoft').length;
```

Comment: thanks, however i am getting an error that producer.filter is not a function in my console

Comment: right, use `Array.from(producers)`, i updated my answer

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

Something along the following lines should work:

```
var producers = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("PRODUCER");
var numOfUbiSoft = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < producers.length; i++) {
    var producer = producers[i];

    if ("UbiSoft" === producer.nodeValue) {
        numOfUbiSoft++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey mate, i tried this and still getting a value of 0 in my console log for that variable.